# Не отображается картинка при отправке из Node.js в браузер

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я написал небольшой сервер для лэндинга. Он полностью работает, но выбивает ошибка при отправке изображения в запросе с браузера. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка.

```js
// --------- Server.js

const http = require('http');
const routing = require('./routing');
const fs = require('fs');
const server = http.Server((req, res) => {
  routing.define(req, res);
}).listen(8000);

// --------- Index.is

const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
const { request } = require('http');

const define = function(req, res) {
  let File__Path = (__dirname + "/main/index.html");
  fs.readFile(File__Path, 'utf-8', (err, html) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "text/html"
    });
    res.end(html);
  })
  const Url__Parsed = url.parse(req.url, true);
  let Path = Url__Parsed.pathname;
  
  if (/\./.test(Path)) {
    if (/\.css$/gi.test(Path)) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/css"
      });
      let Read__Stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/static/css" + Path);
      Read__Stream.pipe(res);
      console.log("The Css file has gone!");
      return;
    } else if (/\.img$/gi.test(Path)) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "image/img"
      });
      let Read__Stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/static/img" + Path);
      Read__Stream.pipe(res);
      console.log("The Img picture is off!");
      return;
    } else if (/\.svg$/gi.test(Path)) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "image/svg"
      });
      let Read__Stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/static/img" + Path);
      Read__Stream.pipe(res);
      console.log("The Svg picture is off!");
      return;
    } else if (/\.jpeg$/gi.test(Path)) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
      });
      let Read__Stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/static/img" + Path);
      Read__Stream.pipe(res);
      console.log("The Jpeg picture is off!");
      return;
    } else if (/\.jpg$/gi.test(Path)) { // The problem is here!!!
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpg"
      });
      fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/static/img/" + Path).pipe(res);
    } else if (/\.png$/gi.test(Path)) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "image/png"
      });
      let Read__Stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/static/img" + Path);
      Read__Stream.pipe(res);
      console.log("The Png picture is off!");
    } else if (/\.js$/gi.test(Path)) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "application/javascript"
      });
      let Read__Stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/static/js" + Path);
      Read__Stream.pipe(res);
      return;
    }
  }
};

exports.define = define;
```

Браузер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: a что-то типа express неспортивно использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Есть две основные проблемы из-за которых не отдаётся картинка.

1. В слюбом случает отдаётся html и завершается соединение.

   ```
   const define = function(req, res) {
       let File__Path = (__dirname + "/main/index.html");
       /* В любом случае происходит чтение файла */
       fs.readFile(File__Path, 'utf-8', (err, html) => {
           res.writeHead(200, {
               "Content-Type": "text/html"
           });
           /* Вот тут мы завершаем вывод */
           res.end(html);
       })
       const Url__Parsed = url.parse(req.url, true);
       let Path = Url__Parsed.pathname;
       /* ... */

   };
   ```
2. Лишнее `"/static/img"`

   ```
   if (/\.jpg$/gi.test(Path)) {
       res.writeHead(200, {
           "Content-Type": "image/jpg"
       });
       // Получается что-то вроде: /tmp/static/img//static/img/asd.jpg
       // Хотя правильный путь:    /tmp/static/img/asd.jpg
       fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/static/img" + Path).pipe(res);
   }
   ```